# Combining all the csv files of monthly page impressions

Tags: python, r, sql-server

I have all the page impressions data with 19 name categories of impressions and around 500 page IDs in each month. These hIDs are almost same in all months except few are different.

I wanted to combine all the 12 months data in a way that all d fee different hIDds which are not common in all are removed and only the common hIDs should be in the file without loosing their data.
Please help me with dis!!

Comment: Python, R, and SQL-Server is a wide variety of options. Do you really not care which of these platforms you get a solution in? (And have you searched for each of them, and really  not been able to even get started? What have you tried??) If this were just an R question, I would probably mark it as a dupe of [this R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Comment: I'd strongly recommend picking a platform, attempting to solve the problem (with some searching to get started), and then, if you get stuck, ask a question showing what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second what Gregor said. Pick a platform and go from there, since any one of these can do what you're asking.

I'm most familiar with python, so I'd use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). I've used it for similar projects, and feel like it's easy to learn and get going.